# Perform animation like kindle app with uicollectionview

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have requirement like below and I went already with couple of animations but it didn't worked me at all..

[image]

please see the image what I want to achieve this kind of animation. I also want centered collectionview cells in which one cell from left and right will appear. This works but not in the full size of screen right now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What code you had written

Comment: I have seen some demos with uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/bignerdranch/iOS7Demos/tree/master/Collections) is good reference.

You have 2 options,

- Use UIView animation, i.e. Scale, Center etc.
- Use UIViewController custom transition

On click of you collectionview's cell you need to show UIView or UIViewController with custom transition.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it.